# How to write methods in typescript which take lambdas as parameters

Tags: typescript, generics, lambda, arrow-functions

My use case is, creating a method that takes a lambda as parameter and returns the value of it.

example :

```
MyModel { id: number , name:string}
const data = new MyModel(1,"Self");

console.log(someMethod(x=> x.id))
```

expected answer: 1

So how do I implement "someMethod" in such a way it takes a lambda as a parameter and gives out the corresponding value.

Comment: is MyModel meant to be a class or an interface?

Comment: How about: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCesD2ATApiaBvawkDsIAXAJwFdgikSAKABzICMQBLYaFlALmnzIFtGaEtAA0DZm2i8w-NF2IkW+AOYBKbAF9omgLAAoPISLQUYImGgBeXmgDucRKgw0AjKIBEAZQwAzD2oA3Aa+ZPiULATQEEhysGhEABaoADwAKgB8NL74PDRIPAjI6CAaVhnQaRpYBtLSJAlkJPjQOTRmFkEGeoYEMSBoAHQgSCo0MXEJySg0AB7l0LODnGpqQA

Comment: @DamianGreen can be the interface also

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

```
const someMethod = (lambda: (x: MyModel) => number) => {
  // ...
}
```